# Specific way to detect custom notification sounds in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-sound

I am currently offering a functionality for my app for which I display all the available system notification sounds to the user.

Now I want to detect the custom notification sounds that may be there in internal memory as well as SD card.

Currently I am thinking of getting a list of all available audio files and then filtering them by their duration (since notification sounds are very short in length).

Is there a better approach to detect custom notification sounds on the device? Answers with corresponding code would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`RingtoneManager.getCursor()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html#getCursor()) gives you a method to get all ringtones. Look below code of [**`RingtoneManager.getCursor()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html#getCursor()).

```
/**
364     * Returns a {@link Cursor} of all the ringtones available. The returned
365     * cursor will be the same cursor returned each time this method is called,
366     * so do not {@link Cursor#close()} the cursor. The cursor can be
367     * {@link Cursor#deactivate()} safely.
368     * <p>
369     * If {@link RingtoneManager#RingtoneManager(Activity)} was not used, the
370     * caller should manage the returned cursor through its activity's life
371     * cycle to prevent leaking the cursor.
372     * <p>
373     * Note that the list of ringtones available will differ depending on whether the caller
374     * has the {@link android.Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE} permission.
375     *
376     * @return A {@link Cursor} of all the ringtones available.
377     * @see #ID_COLUMN_INDEX
378     * @see #TITLE_COLUMN_INDEX
379     * @see #URI_COLUMN_INDEX
380     */
381    public Cursor getCursor() {
382        if (mCursor != null && mCursor.requery()) {
383            return mCursor;
384        }
385
386        final Cursor internalCursor = getInternalRingtones();
387        final Cursor mediaCursor = getMediaRingtones();
388
389        return mCursor = new SortCursor(new Cursor[] { internalCursor, mediaCursor },
390                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
391    }
```

Comment: Thanks :) I had already implemented this in my app. Looks like I need to instruct my users to move their custom sounds to specific Notification folders and then my existing code works like a charm :) Thanks a lot :)